# Editing Blenderkit Model Materials

Tags: texturing, materials, edit-mode, properties, blenderkit

Have downloaded a blender kit model, I've figured out how to change from link to append to alter the location and scale etc of individual objects within the model. Is there a way to edit the materials automatically applied? I can't seem to put any of the objects into edit mode to see the UV map, and the material properties is all greyed out and says I'm blocked from changing these things. Is it possible to change the material on an already textured object?